# What is the Syntax of Filter in OData query Message Trace API

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm trying to build a URL that fetches a message trace with userA@aia.com as a recipient between the dates of "2023-08-09' and '2023-08-11' and I want it to filter on the Subject,Status,RecipientAddress,SenderAddress,Received .

When I run this query, I get all messages received by the recipient for the past 2 days. Not what I want. Can someone please point me out to the correct query?

https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MessageTrace?filter=startDate eq datetime'2023-08-09' and endDate eq datetime'2023-08-11' and RecipientAddress eq 'userA@aia.com'&$select=Subject,Received,SenderAddress,RecipientAddress,Status

Regards,

Alexis

I was expecting only data from usera@aia.com from dates specified in the URL.